# How to close the console in the geth console

Tags: ethereum

In Ethereum I opened the javascript console with "geth console" but I can not close it anymore.

I have tried `ctrl-c`, but it does not work.

Answer (score 15):

Just type `exit`on the geth console

Answer (score 7):

`Ctrl + c` is the shortcut to clear the input prompt.`Ctrl + d` will exit the console when the input line is clear.

Alternatively, you can type the command `exit`